# How do you clear Static variables in PHP?

Tags: php, static-variables

I have created a function which is using **recursion to find out childs of Given User**. as shown below :

```
function recursionFunc($param) {
  $q = "select cust_id,amount,position from testtab where parent_id = $param";
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    static $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            $i++;
            recursionFunc($row['cust_id']);
        }
    return array('totalChild'=>$i);

}
```

> There are two cases:
>
> 1. I want to call recursionFunc() for each user i am having
> 2. Recursion will be done in order to find childs of a user.

Now i want to call this function in while loop in order to fetch childs of all user i am having.
Since i am using static variable **$i** to store the value of childs.

Now when function will be called for the **first user it returns correct value of childs but return wrong value in all other cases**.

AS show Below

```
$cutData = "select cust_id from testtab";
$ress = mysql_query($cutData);
while ($raw = mysql_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
    $response = recursionFunc($raw['cust_id']);
    echo '<pre>'.$raw['cust_id'];
    print_r($response);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Outputs

```
1Array ( [totalChild] => 7 ) 2Array ( [totalChild] => 10 ) 3Array ( [totalChild] => 12 )
```

It will be great if you can help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use: `unset()`

Comment: Why did you use static? If you wouldn't use static you mustn't unset it

Comment: Why are using static when it can change at any time.Static variables are which are not change through out'

Comment: Why on earth would you use a static variable for this?  Recursively querying a database also seems like a potential problem.  It would probably be better to get all the relevant records in one query and then recurse over the result as needed.

Comment: I uses static variable to keep track of how many times my function is called . If i will not user static keyword it will reinitialize $i variable eachtime recursionFunc() called.

Comment: There are two cases:
1. I will call recursionFunc()  for each user i am having.
2. Recursion is done in order to find child of each user.

Comment: @user3769872: Am I reading this wrong, or is `recursionFunc()` (which is a *very* unhelpful name for a function) returning *only* the count of how many times it executed?  If so, then instead of incrementing `$i` by one, increment it by the number returned from the recursive function call.  The top-level recursive call would then get the aggregate total of all subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. But actually i have to find some other attributes too. Thats why I am returning array.

Comment: I think the "normal" way is to send $i as an argument to the recursive call like recursionFunc($row['cust_id'], $i++);